# How can I modify the style when hovering over a combo's option?

Tags: xpages

This sounds so very simple:

hovering over the options of an Xpages comboBox they get some blue-ish background and white text color. Trying to alter this is driving me nuts. It obviously is NOT a simple css statement as in

```
select option:hover{background-color: green;}
```

as it would be for some standard html code (that's why I didn't tag this with css and the like...). But what is it then? Firebug or Chrome's developer tools didn't help me much, really, although I'm sure I'm missing something

*Edit (after question was closed):*
I'm aware that there are numerous questions regarding similar topics. But none of them is dealing with xsp combo boxes. The one question linked by some of youo gives an interesting solution by recommending a box-shadow instead of a background-color. This is nice but not quite what I'm looking for:

- opening the combo the selected value still has the default
  background; only whil hovering the background appears to be changed
- using this method I only can "cast" a shadow but cannot alter the
  text color which - depending on the shadow color - can be necessary
  to make the options legible

But I like Knut's answer as it seems to be pointing in the right direction; some alterations are needed though; if the question hadn't been closed I could post my solution as an own answer; but so I put it down as a comment to Knut's answer

Comment: What web browser(s) are you looking to support?

Comment: That's **not** really a **duplicate** question as it is XPages related: *first*, you have to know that `xp:comboBox` gets rendered as a native HTML select control (and that's why hover background can't be changed) and *second* there is an alternative out of the box with `xe:djComboBox`.

Comment: Re: @user2191572: it's supposed to support MSIE 8--10 and Chrome; but in fact it should work in any modern browser

Comment: Re: @Knut: thanks for the input, and I agree: searching StackOverflow I had found numerous questions and answers, but all dealing with standard HTML select controls

Comment: I'm glad to see you got it working, I think the root issue in question stems from the rules of style specificity. Feel free to read up on it if you have some free time. [smashingmagazine.com](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: +1 for that great article! It's going to be of some help in the future, I'm sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change this style for `xp:comboBox`. But, if you use `xe:djComboBox` from ExtLib then you can change style with:

```
.tundra .dijitMenuItemSelected  {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer which pointed in the right direction. I had to apply some alterations though, as "dijitMenuItemSelected" only applies for the short moment of clicking the item. For Hovering I finally found that "dijitMenuItem:hover" does the trick; I also tried "dijitMenuItemHover" which is applied while hovering the items, but somehow this one isn't triggering a change in style.

Comment: Thanks for adding "dijitMenuItem:hover" although hovering works for me with just "dijitMenuItemSelected" (Notes 8.5.3) - might depend on version or browser - it's good to have your final solution.